# What Google Play Services version is needed for AppInvites to run?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

I am trying to set up [App Invites](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/) beta library in my application.

The guide suggests to add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0’
```

with 8.4 being the latest version, but actually I want to stick with v. `7.8` (or so) for a while, because in my experience lots of devices are still below, and if they install my app they’ll be asked to update their play services. Nothing wrong, but I just want to stick with that version for a while.

I couldn’t find any info about that on the official docs.

Comment: It seems Google is suggesting to use the latest Play Service version based on the [Add App Invites to Your App](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app) page of the App Invites for Android documentation/

Comment: Well, they suggest latest version everywhere. Still, for a production app it might make sense to stick with an older version for a while, just not to break code and bother users. Don't know, I'm also facing compile issues right now and can't focus on this question.

Comment: I had to remove the *com.google.gms.google-services* plugin or it wouldn't compile with 8.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppInvites was [first released](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/google-play-services-81-get-ready-for.html) in Play Services 8.1. It received a fairly significant [update](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-play-services-84-sdk-is-available_18.html) in 8.4, but before that it didn't change much from what I can tell.